Drill Small Hole in 2 Inch Wood Ball
I am trying to drill a 1/4 hole in a 2-inch diameter hardwood ball (sphere). Not all the way through, about 1/2 inch deep, to insert a dowel. I would like the position and angle to be good enough so I can spin the dowel in my fingers and the ball remains visually stationary.
Here is what I tried. I clamped a scrap piece of plywood in my drill press. I drilled a 1-1/2-inch hole with a spade bit. With the scrap wood still clamped, I removed the spade bit and put in the 1/4 bit. I put the ball in the indentation, held it with my hand, and slowly drilled. The result was poor, probably not any better than I could have done without the alignment jig.
Maybe if I used a Forstner bit and had a cleaner hole I would get better results. I have a few, but nothing that big.
Are there any other techniques to try? I have a beginner's shop. Portable table saw, miter saw, drill press. No lathe.
Edit: Success. I made three changes and now I have the accuracy that I want. I don't know which were most important, maybe all three helped.

Drilled jig with a Forstner bit (1 inch).

Spun the ball on a table to find the preferred axis.

Used a brad point bit to drill the small hole.




How confident are you that the wooden ball is close to perfectly spherical? I would verify that as well.  If it's not, it might still have a perfect circle somewhere, and positioning the hole 90 degrees to the plane of the perfect circle should help you achieve a satisfying spin.

The rudimentary jig you created should indeed have resulted in a perfectly aligned drilled hole, because the two holes created would by definition be in line with the quill. But various factors can throw this off.
The spade bit could indeed have been the cause of the problem (I think especially because it was so big, 1.5" is really very large for a spade bit) but not necessarily. Spade bits vary loads in how good they are, from truly awful in every way to extremely good and everything in between; if the bit was of sufficient quality a hole drilled with it (esp. in a drill press) could result in hole as near to perfectly circular as needed for 90% of uses.
Runout — wobble of the bit in chuck, or the chuck on its spindle, or both — might possibly be the cause, or a contributing factor. While runout in older (worn) drill presses and in newer (poorly made) drill presses is not uncommon, it's rarely so bad that it isn't instantly visible with a bit in the chuck (drill running) so I doubt that alone this is the reason or you'd have spotted it yourself.
Your mention of Forstners yielding a cleaner hole (which they most definitely should, by default) suggests that the hole you got wasn't that clean, i.e. had ragged edges (a common feature of holes drilled with less-than-stellar spade bits), and that could very much be the entirety of the issue since of course it means the ball can't sit neatly into it, such that all of the rim contacts the ball.
It also occurs to me that given the diameter of the ball relative to this large hole in the ply that the ball might bottom out before seating on the rim of the hole anyway, but that seems unlikely since the drill-press table presumably has a hole in its centre which would prevent this possibility. Plus again I would imagine you'd notice this holding the ball in place with your hand.

I have a few [Forstner bits] but nothing that big.

The positioning hole doesn't have to be that big. In fact only a ~1/2" hole should work just fine.
The only thing the jig's hole needs to do is seat the ball, aligned with the quill of the drill press...... as long as the ball doesn't move during drilling the 1/4" will be aligned because again by definition the holes are in line with the quill. A larger hole simply makes the seating easier and more secure, not more accurate.
